# Pig - Multiple Values For Key

Tags: key, apache-pig, key-value

I have written a Pig script that will perform some image processing via Python UDFs.

After doing some operations, I have something like (for example):

```
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (name:chararray, pixelIntensity:float);

B = group A by pixelIntensity;

dump B;
```

B is then something like this:

```
(131.0,{(image1,jpg,131.0), (image2.jpg,131.0), (image3.jpg,131.0)})
(140.0,{(image5.jpg,140.0), (image5.jpg,140.0)})
(150.0,{(image4.jpg,150.0})
```

If I were to go

```
dump A;
```

I'd get the following:

```
(image1.jpg,131.0)
(image2.jpg,131.0)
(image3.jpg,131.0)
(image4.jpg,150.0)
(image5.jpg,140.0)
```

So I've basically grouped them using their average pixel intensity as the key.

My question is this:

Am I able to extract only 1 element from each row in B? So for example, I'll have like

```
(image1.jpg,131.0)
(image4.jpg,150.0)
...
```

Comment: I know Pig has a LIMIT construct, though I'm not sure it can be used along side GROUP <relation> BY...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested `FOREACH` with a `LIMIT` should do what you want:

```
A = LOAD 'data' using PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,pixelIntensity:float);
B = GROUP A BY pixelIntensity;
C = FOREACH B {
    D = LIMIT A 1;
    GENERATE flatten(D);
};
STORE C INTO 'res';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Fred! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

May I please also ask how that nested `FOREACH` works? From what I see, you take only the top entry from A, but why the `flatten(D)` part?